# String#codePointAt ou String#charCodeAt?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

No ECMAScript 6 foram adicionados novos métodos semelhantes à `String.fromCharCode()` e `String#charCodeAt()`: `String.fromCodePoint()` e `String#codePointAt()`.

Qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 0):

Da documentação:

```
String.fromCodePoint()
```

> O método estático String.fromCodePoint() retorna uma seqüência de caracteres criado usando a seqüência especificada de pontos de código

```
String.prototype.codePointAt()
```

> O método codePointAt() retorna um inteiro não-negativo que é o código
>   Unicode do ponto de código

Links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint

Answer (score 0):

A diferença é simples. Primeiro, [um valor do tipo String](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-string-value) (mais expressado como "string") armazena uma sequência de números inteiros não negativos, do tamanho de 2 bytes (16 bits), chamados "elementos" para facilitar a referência.

O método [`String#charCodeAt(índice)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.charcodeat), por exemplo, apenas retorna o valor do elemento na *índice* (que por convenção inicia do `0`) especificada como um número. O método estático [`String.fromCharCode(...códigos)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.fromcharcode) retorna um valor do tipo String, onde cada elemento equivale à cada código dado.

Agora, a diferença de [`String#codePointAt(índice)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.codepointat). Baseado na codificação UTF-16, retorna o código do caractere na *índice* (índice dos elementos, não do código) dada.

O método estático [`String.fromCodePoint(...códigos)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.fromcodepoint) também diferencia de `String.fromCharCode()` por conta da codificação UTF-16 (cria dois elementos se precisar de *surrogate pairs* para representar o código de um caractere), mas enfim, não dá excepções para códigos entre `0xD800` e `0xDFFF` (certamente deveria).